# Is there a Symfony2 CRUD Generator

Tags: php, symfony, crud

I know there is a simple CRUD generator built in in Symfony2 but that CRUD has no features.

Is there a CRUD Generator Project that takes a config or Table and generates the Controller & View files?

If not - are there Projects I can contribute to?

thx for all help :)

Comment: Have you been to [packagist](https://packagist.org/search/?q=symfony%20crud)?

Comment: I was but most of the CRUD generator are for cake or ZF2 - I found "jordillonch" generator but it has a problem with tables where the primary key is not called "id"

Answer (score 0):

The most popular ones might be [the Sonata Project](http://sonata-project.org/) and [the AdminGeneratorBundle](http://symfony2admingenerator.org/).

Hope that helps
Chris